# Implementing multiple interfaces in java

Tags: java

In Java this is valid

```
 interface  Iface1{
    void func();
}

 interface  Iface2{
    void func();
}

class Demo implements Iface1, Iface2 {
    public void func(){

    }
}
```

but why is this not valid

```
interface Iface1 {
    void func(Integer a);
}

interface Iface2 {
    void func(Object a);
}

class Demo implements Iface1, Iface2 {
    public void func(Integer a) {
    }
}
```

In this case, since I implement Iface1, the contract of both Iface1 and Iface2 are fulfilled. Since Integer is a subclass of Object.

The compiler gives me error - Class 'Demo' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'func(Object)' in 'Iface2'

I was expecting this should work by only implementing the function with parameter Integer type

Comment: Second Demo class doesn't implement Iface2.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the Iface2

Comment: Because it is valid to call `Iface2 a = new Demo(); a.func("test");` and your implementation cannot handle that.

Comment: technically `func(Integer)` is not the same [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) as `func(Object)` - and you do not even need multiple interfaces for that problem: `class Demo implements Iface2 { public void func(Integer a) { } }` will also not work

Comment: Looks like you are not even trying this code in an IDE. The compiler will tell you that Demo class doesn't implement Iface2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iface2` declares `func` to accept any `Object`, so to implement that interface, a class must provide an implementation of `func` accepting any `Object`. For instance, the call `demoInstance.func("this is a string")` must be valid.

`Demo`'s `func` only accepts `Integer`s so it does not implement the interface.

In your first setup, the signature of both methods is the same in both interfaces, so there's a valid implementation for either in `Demo`.

Comment: Makes sense, btw if i implement just Iface1 and in Demo class i implement a function which accepts an object, should it not satisfy the contract since Object is superclass of Integer

Comment: You're right that the contract should be satisfied in Java if a class implements an interface and has a function that takes an object parameter. You can also give an implementation that takes a subclass parameter. Here, it's important to remember that the implementing class method must accept at least the type of parameter that is listed in the interface.